# jQuery 1.6.2 erroring with Operation is not supported" code: "9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting the following error in firebug: jQuery 1.6.2 erroring with Operation is not supported" code: "9. Firstly can someone tell me the exact meaning of this error? Secondly, what I am doing is using dialog to display a form, which displays fine, but whenever I click in an input field, it triggers this error. I have attached my code and would be grateful for some guidance:

jQuery 1.6.2
jQuery-ui 1.8.14

```
// Help function

function help() {

    $(function () {

        $('#feedback').dialog({
            resizeable: true,
            title: "Mail Help",
            width: 500,
            height: 420,
            modal: true,
            overlay: {
                backgroundColor: "#000",
                opacity: 0.3
            }


        });
        $("feedback").dialog('open');
    });
}


// Feedback form
<div id="form" style="display:none;">
  <form method="post" id="feedback" class="webform" name="feedback">


        <label for="company">Company</label>
        <select name="company" id="company">
                <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="Technical">Technical</option>
                <option value="Database">Database</option>
                <option value="Error">Error</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
                <input id="uname" name="uname"  type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox uname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['kt_name_usr']; ?>" />
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['kt_email_usr']; ?>" />
        <label for="position">Position:</label>
                <input id="position" name="position" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox position" />
        <label for="feedbacknew">Feedback:</label>
                <textarea id="feedbacknew" name="feedbacknew" cols="25" rows="3" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox feedbacknew">Please make sure that any error messages or numbers are listed here </textarea><br />

        <button id="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
        <div id="message"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe trying to make FORM to dialog is problem (not sure), try DIV instead

Comment: @pezhavk dosen't make any difference. thanks

Comment: Seems to be working just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/VWbE9/1/

Comment: @petersen check out the error in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DQGNS/

Comment: @bollo `$.dialog('open');` is not valid you need `$("selector").dialog('open');`

Comment: Which browser are you getting the error on?

Comment: @petersen I had selector: $("feedback").dialog('open'); in my orginal code. Thought I would try something different and forgot to change.

Comment: The same error is happening here in my code. It looks like it's some problem with jquery 1.6.2 in FF3.5 .

Answer (score 2):

Found how to fix it in some of my cases.

In jQuery source (not min) find this block:

```
if ( document.documentElement.contains ) {
    Sizzle.contains = function( a, b ) {
        return a !== b && (a.contains ? a.contains(b) : true);
    };

} else if ( document.documentElement.compareDocumentPosition ) {
    Sizzle.contains = function( a, b ) {
        return !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);
    };

} else {
    Sizzle.contains = function() {
        return false;
    };
}
```

and add the try-catch for the line `return !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);`

```
if ( document.documentElement.contains ) {
    Sizzle.contains = function( a, b ) {
        return a !== b && (a.contains ? a.contains(b) : true);
    };

} else if ( document.documentElement.compareDocumentPosition ) {
    Sizzle.contains = function( a, b ) {
        try {
            return !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false
        }
    };

} else {
    Sizzle.contains = function() {
        return false;
    };
}
```

Why it happens you can read [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-compareDocumentPosition) in the Exceptions section.